# difference bitween saveOrUpdate and merge using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

What's the difference between [saveOrUpdate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate%28java.lang.Object%29) and [merge](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29) using hibernate and sessionFactory?

Answer (score 0):

**Hibernate saveOrUpdate**

- results into insert or update queries based on the provided data. If
  the data is present in the database, update query is executed.

**Hibernate merge**

- can be used to update existing values, however this method create a
  copy from the passed entity object and return it. The returned object
  is part of persistent context and tracked for any changes, passed
  object is not tracked. This is the major difference with merge() from
  all other methods used to save data